# merge of directories in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I merged  directories in two different views using clearcase. The directories can have difference in the no. of files and subdirectories.

After merge The listing of files merged on merge manager doesnot match with no. of files 
checkedout on to-clearcase view.

ie. lsco on the merged-to view and 
    No. of files checked out on merge manager(I didn't checkout any files prior to merge operation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the history of the two versions of a directory being merged from one branch to another:

- if one version has removed files (i.e. has  less files than the other version)
- if said version is merged onto the other,

the resulting version will have less files than initially shown in the view.

That could be because:

- that view is not the one used for the merge
- that view is the correct one, but with an eclipsed or hijacked content (privates files replacing versioned files)

In any case, what would help in the mentioned view is:

- a '`cleartool ls`' in the directory merged
- a '`cleartool ls`' in the parent directory of the directory merged.

The output of those two commands would help to confirm the exact status of the files merged within that directory, as well as the status of the directory itself.

Comment: I've 1096 files .. lsco is difficult to trace. Are view private files shown in co state?

Comment: @Vignesh: yes, view private files would show up with `ct ls` even with a directory checked out. Not `ct lsco`. I was asking about a `ct ls` to check each file status.

Comment: @VonC.. I want to know if the 1. 'Merge from' files which are not present in 'Merge to' are made view private 2. Files which were not in the to folder and are added newly are checked out after version is made.. For text files

Comment: @Vignesh: if you have files which are not included in the file manager list, then they are left as is (private is they were private). For your 2.: not sure, but I believe they are left checked-out, yes.

Comment: I h've edited my previous comment. Can you Reply based on tht?

Comment: I'll do a merge again something got screwed Thanks a lot:)

Comment: Is there a way to export the list of files merged using merge manager to a text file?

Comment: @Vignesh: not sure through the GUI. The simplest way would be to to in in a shell session, with the CLI (`cleartool findmerge...`). That way, you can redirect the output in a file.

Comment: Is there a way to delete the files from destination that are not in source during a merge?

Comment: @Vignesh I don't think so. you need to list them through a script and rmname them.